# How can I keep my privacy while owning multiple domain names?

Tags: domains, domain-registration, whois, privacy

I want to own, create and run few domains. I do not want 'whois' to have my name, home address and home phone available to anyone who looks me up.

I've already bought a mailbox that I can use for my physical address. But... that doesn't get my name and number question answered. What is the best way to be anonymous yet still be legal? Do I need to incorporate all my sites and get an LLC? Can I create a company name without becoming an LLC?

Then there's the phone number....
Thanks in advance to all who respond!

Comment: I'm voting to close as too localized. There are tons of top level domains and not all of them have same registration requirements and may have different levels of background checking. If you want some privacy, you could take a look at registrars which support WHOIS privacy, but proper authorities will still have your information. It just won't be as easy to access. I know that there's option for that at co.cc. As or company, well that depends on where you are and what your local regulations are. I'd be surprised if you could open a company with no information and keep it legal.

Answer (score 5):

Business registration is not the most economical solution to achieve privacy - see Wikipedia's [domain privacy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_privacy) article for the more common means of achieving privacy without providing false information.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about your registrar, but I know that GoDaddy offers private registration. What happens is that it's the address of the company that handles your private registry. When correspondence is sent to you, it's sent to the company and they forward it to you (so only THEY know your info.)
It works the same for email, too. So, for example, if a person wanted to contact you, they would see your email address on the whois is something like
qwertyhouiefhiw73298@privateregistrycompany.com.
The email is sent to that address and then when that address receives the email, the email is then forwarded to your account. Nifty, eh?

Sad part is that I found all that out by trying to contact a guy who had stolen content from my website. :(

Answer (score 1):

Using a domain privacy service is the best way to protect your personal information. Just be aware that not all domain extensions allow privacy. If a domain extension does not allow it, no registrar will be able to offer privacy for it. Most domains do allow privacy. Your registrar should have information available on which domains allow it versus which don't.

Answer (score 0):

### Privacy Registration

Most domain registrars offer this.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to go for Domain Name Privacy. Though it should be offered for free, most registrars charge an annual fee of about $10 per domain for domain name privacy. Once you have the privacy setup, your details shall not be visible in the Whois searches.

Comment: Why answer a question with the same answer that someone else already provided 2 years ago?